# SSRS Generic Drop Down Month Parameter

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, parameters, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012. I'm trying to create a simple drop down parameter to show generic month/year over a given timeframe, lets say last 5 or 6 years (for example... Sept 2016, Oct 2016, etc).

Edit: My goal with this is that I have a StartDate field for a record and all records that fall within a certain Month, I want to capture with the parameter.

I have already been using a parameter for Start Date and End Date using Date/Time field when creating my parameter to get a range. I no longer wish to use that because my end user wants it simply by month/year.

This is the code I have which shows only the Month of the Start Date right now. How do I amend this code to show Month and Year?

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATENAME(month,A.[STRT_DTTM]) AS [Month]
FROM    Work as A
WHERE A.[STRT_DTTM] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY DATENAME(month,A.[STRT_DTTM])
```

Additionally once code is amended, how would I go about this to sort month by normal calendar flow (aka Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr...?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try SSRS, which you probably have - 
Then have a look at this - Basically you choose the 'Date' type for the drop down parameter: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337401(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: That's what I was using before and while a range is nice and useful. Unfortunately, it's not what my end user wants.

Comment: Basically did what you said, but added expressions for 1st and last day of current month. Not initially what I wanted to do, but it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATENAME(month,A.[STRT_DTTM]) AS [Month]
FROM    Work as A
WHERE A.[STRT_DTTM] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY DATENAME(month,A.[STRT_DTTM])
```